# Global scope vs global namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope, terminology

I saw usages of these two phrases: global scope and global namespace. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In C++, every name has its scope outside which it doesn't exist. A scope can be defined by many ways : it can be defined by *namespace*, *functions*,  *classes* and just *{ }*.

So a namespace, global or otherwise, defines a scope. The global namespace refers to using `::`, and the symbols defined in this namespace are said to have global scope. A symbol, by default, exists in a global namespace, unless it is defined inside a block starts with keyword `namespace`, or it is a member of a class, or a local variable of a function:

```
int a; //this a is defined in global namespace
       //which means, its scope is global. It exists everywhere.

namespace N
{
     int a;  //it is defined in a non-global namespace called `N`
             //outside N it doesn't exist.
}
void f()
{
   int a;  //its scope is the function itself.
           //outside the function, a doesn't exist.
   {
        int a; //the curly braces defines this a's scope!
   }
}
class A
{
   int a;  //its scope is the class itself.
           //outside A, it doesn't exist.
};
```

Also note that a *name* can be hidden by inner scope defined by either namespace, function, or class. So the name `a` inside namespace `N` hides the name `a` in the global namspace. In the same way, the name in the function and class hides the name in the global namespace. If you face such situation, then you can use `::a` to refer to the name defined in the global namespace:

```
int a = 10;

namespace N
{
    int a = 100;

    void f()
    {
         int a = 1000;
         std::cout << a << std::endl;      //prints 1000
         std::cout << N::a << std::endl;   //prints 100 
         std::cout << ::a << std::endl;    //prints 10
    }
}
```

Comment: What should we do if we want to access 'a' (defined in namespaces N) inside function void f(){}

Comment: @rimiro: If `a` is declared in a function scope, you cannot access it from *outside* the function.

Comment: So a namespace is one kind of a scope?

Comment: @JozefMikušinec.. Yes.. :-)

Answer (score 7):

When you declare a global variable `int i` for example, we say `i is in the global namespace` and `has the global namespace scope`. That's all.

*Excerpt From C++03:*

```
3.3.5 Namespace scope   

    The outermost declarative region of a translation unit is also a namespace, called
  the global namespace. A name declared in the global namespace has global namespace
  scope (also called global scope).
```

Answer (score 7):

"Scope" is a more general term than "namespace". Every namespace, class and code block defines a scope in which names declared inside it can be used; a namespace is a container for names declared outside classes and functions.

"Global scope" and "global namespace" can be used more or less interchangeably; the scope of a name declared in a namespace covers the whole of that namespace. Use "namespace" if you're specifically referring to the namespace, and "scope" if you're referring to the visibility of names inside it.

Answer (score 7):

Scope denotes the lifetime of an object, you can have a global variable that will exist as long as your program executes, or you can have a variable with a block scope that will exist as long as that block of code executes. Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>

int a = 100;

main () {
    int a = 200;

    std::cout << "local a is: " << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "global a is: " << ::a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When executed the statement will print `local a is: 200`, that is expected obviously, because we're redefining `a` in `main` which leaves in the scope of it's enclosing block. We also print the global `::a` which again prints the expected value 100, because we have asked for the global namespace `::`.

A namespace semantics are mostly logical, it is a way of isolating symblos from one another, in the hope to avoid name clashes, it does not affect the lifespan of an object.

Scope on the other hand, denotes the lifespan of an object, the global `a` sprung into existence before the local `a` because it gets constructed much earlier than main gets executed. However, scope also *forces* a namespace on the symbol, but not in the same way that a `namespace` does. There are different kind of scopes, `global`, `class`, `function`, `block`, `file` etc...

The confusing part is that scope is sometimes overloaded to denote the visibility of a particular symbol, which is something borrowed from C, where the notion of namespaces did not exist and scope was used to denote both, lifespan and visibility. In C++, however the rules changed a bit,but the term *scope* is still used the same way because the two languages share a great deal of concepts.

Comment: Good that you highlighted the idea that a scope is inherent to an object's lifetime.

Answer (score 4):

@Dmitriy Ryajov

The topic is a little bit old but I want to offer my help about this. I think that you should not make things more complicated than they really are. `Scope` of an identifier is the part of a computer program where the identifier, a name that refers to some entity in the program, can be used to find the referred entity. So the term scope only applies to identifiers and we should not mix it with the lifetime of the object. They are somewhat connected but should not be mixed up. The lifetime of the object is denoted by where we allocate the memory for that object. So, for example, if a memory is allocated on the stack, it will be freed as soon as the function finishes. So it depends on where we store the object and that denotes its lifetime. The scope only says: "Here is a name for an object and we can use this name for the object till then and then". So, as I said, the term `scope` is only for identifiers of the objects and the lifetime is something else wich is denoted by where we store the object.

Additionally, I want to say something about `linkage` which is closely related to this. This can be also sometimes confusing. Let's say we have some identifiers in the `translation unit` that refer to some objects. Whether the same identifiers in `other` translation unit will refer to the same entities is denoted by the linkage. So, for example, if an identifier has an external linkage, we can refer to the entity that this identifier refers to but from other translation unit by declaring it with keyword `extern`. Now, let's say we don't want to use that entity in other translation units. Then, the entity will `exist` till the program finishes but when we don't declare it, we won't be able to refer to it. Also note that now i mixed the terms linkage and lifetime. But this is because only `global` entities have external linkage. An identifier inside a function can't be refered to from the other parts of the program.

Conclusion: Always try to keep things simple. I was surprised how different people talk about these terms differently. The whole process of separate compilation is confusing, because there are multiple terms which have almost the same meaning and probably everyone will get stuck at this point.