# Can you start a class name with a numeric digit?

Tags: c++, class, naming

In *C++*, is it possible to start a class name with a *digit*?  For example,

```
template <class T> class 2DArray {

public:
    // 1D ARRAY CLASS
    class 1DArray {
    public:
        1DArray() { Create(); }
        1DArray(iterator arr) : array1d_(arr) { }
        explicit 1DArray(size_type cols, const T& t = T()) { Create(cols, t); }
        1DArray(const 1DArray& arr) { Create(arr.begin(), arr.end()); }
        1DArray& operator=(const 2DArray&);
        ~1DArray() { Uncreate(); }

        T& operator[](size_type n) {
            return array1d_[n];
        }
        const T& operator[](size_type n) const {
            return array1d_[n];
        }
}
```

Comment: you may have the numeric digits at the bottom of class name...

Comment: Rename it to Array, since it's by default.. one dimension. Then if you have a 2 dimensional one call it Array2D.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Rules for identifier names in *C++* are:

1. It can not start with a number
2. Can be composed of letters, numbers, underscore, universal character names<sup>1</sup> and *implementation defined* characters
3. Can not be a [keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

The sections in the [C++ draft standard](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.open-std.org%2Fjtc1%2Fsc22%2Fwg21%2Fdocs%2Fpapers%2F2012%2Fn3485.pdf&ei=z0bLUfHdNuno0wH744HADQ&usg=AFQjCNHADNpAEY3AIbLLCRGSrJcS5QWcEg&bvm=bv.48340889,d.dmQ&cad=rja) that cover this are `2.11` *Identifiers* which includes the following grammar:

```
identifier:
  identifier-nondigit            <- Can only start with a non-digit
  identifier identifier-nondigit <- Next two rules allows for subsequent 
  identifier digit               <-  characters to be those outlined in 2 above
identifier-nondigit:
  nondigit                       <- a-z, A-Z and _ 
  universal-character-name
  other implementation-defined characters
[...]
```

and `2.12` *Keywords* explains all the *identifier* reserved for use as keywords.

Finally, the following names are also reserved:

1. Names that contain a double underscore `__`, or start with either an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (like `_Apple`) in any scope,
2. Names that start with an underscore in the global namespace (like `_apple` in the global namespace) are reserved.

The section that covers this in the *draft standard* is `17.6.4.3.2`. We can find a rationale for why these are reserved from [Rationale for International Standard—Programming Languages—C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf") which says:

> [...]This gives a name space for writing the numerous behind-the-scenes non-external macros and functions a library needs to do its job properly[...]

In *C++* this also applies to  [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) as this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Complex_example) shows.

---

Footnotes

- **1. Allowed universal characters**

The universal characters that are allowed is covered in `Annex E.1`:

> E.1 Ranges of characters allowed [charname.allowed]
>
> 00A8, 00AA, 00AD,
>
> 00AF, 00B2-00B5, 00B7-00BA, 00BC-00BE, 00C0-00D6, 00D8-00F6, 00F8-00FF
>
> 0100-167F, 1681-180D, 180F-1FFF 200B-200D, 202A-202E, 203F-2040, 2054,
>
> 2060-206F 2070-218F, 2460-24FF, 2776-2793, 2C00-2DFF, 2E80-2FFF
>
> 3004-3007, 3021-302F, 3031-303F
>
> 3040-D7FF F900-FD3D, FD40-FDCF,
>
> FDF0-FE44, FE47-FFFD
>
> 10000-1FFFD, 20000-2FFFD, 30000-3FFFD,
>   40000-4FFFD, 50000-5FFFD, 60000-6FFFD, 70000-7FFFD, 80000-8FFFD,
>   90000-9FFFD, A0000-AFFFD, B0000-BFFFD, C0000-CFFFD, D0000-DFFFD, 
>   E0000-EFFFD

Comment: This is really true of any C-like language too, or at the very least almost all.

Comment: Clarification: Contain a double underscore or start with an underscore followed by a capital letter, or start with an underscore in the global scope.

Comment: @AthomSfere, in C, names that contain `__` are not reserved, only those _starting_ with it.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is no. For you example why not call it OneDArray?

Comment: That's ugly, and you're solving the wrong problem. Instead of substituting the digit with something else, why not change the name to, say, `Array1D`?

Answer (score 4):

Since, surprisingly, I wasn't able to find a duplicate, or more general version, of this question, here is an answer based on what the Standard (C++11) says.

First of all, by §9/1, a class name is an *identifier* (or a *simple-template-id* in the case of a template specialization, but a *simple-template-id* is also composed of *identifiers*).

§2.11 defines what a valid *identifier* is. It first introduces a few basic concepts:

A *digit* is one of these: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
A *nondigit* is one of these: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`
A *universal-character-name* is a sequence of type `\unnnn` or `\Unnnnnnnn` (where each `n` is a hexadecimal digit)

The Standard then defines an *identifier-nondigit* as

- either a *nondigit*
- or a *universal-character-name*
- or an implementation-defined special character<sup>(‡)</sup>

Finally, *identifier* is defined recursively as

> *identifier*:
>     *identifier-nondigit*
>     *identifier* *identifier-nondigit*
>     *identifier* *digit*

**Summary: In other words, an identifier must start with a (non-digit!) alphabetical character, which can be followed by anything made up of alphanumerical characters, underscores and `\unnnn`-like character references. Anything else is implementation-specific.**

---

<sup>(‡)</sup> Whether any are supported depends on your compiler, and using them generally means you lose portability to other compilers or compiler versions.

Comment: Thank you for the clear summary, though I am not sure why it was surprising.  If I found the answer on Google or Stack Overflow, I wouldn't have asked.  The recursive standard-speak, too, eludes my simple brain; my understanding got as far as the class name being an identifier, and then the identifier identifier-nondigit part just makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Cindeselia Yes, of course. I wasn't surprised by your asking the question. I am surprised about the fact nobody asked it before.

Comment: @Cindeselia Oh, regarding the _identifier_ definition: You need to read every line as an alternative. So an _identifier_ is either a _identifier-nondigit_, or _identifier_ followed by _identifier-nondigit_ or _identifier_ followed by _digit_. So, _identifier_ occurs in its own definition and can be recursively replaced with further instances of that definition. Any sequence you can possibly form from this will always start with an _identifier-non-digit_.

Answer (score 1):

Names in C++ must start with a 'letter', where letter is all the upper and lower case 'A-Z, a-z'. '_' also counts as a 'letter'. It can then be followed by any combination of letters and digits.

Comment: So _2DArray should be okay?

Comment: @Cindeselia depends, any names in the global namespace that starts with an `_` is reserved and should not used. This previous thread clarifies global Vs. non-global namespaces in case you are not sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269012/global-scope-vs-global-namespace

Comment: @Cindeselia This previous thread suggests not using leading underscores in names just to sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224397/why-do-people-use-double-underscore-so-much-in-c