# "unexpected in macro definition"

Tags: c++, macros

I wrote

```
#ifndef Header1.h
#define Header1.h

class Complex
{
   [...]
};

#endif
```

in my project (Visual Studio 2010) and I get an Error C2008: '.' : unexpected in macro definition. I don't understand what the problem is with "Header1.h" or how to fix it.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear... there's nothing we can do apart from restate it - you can't used `.` in a macro name.

Comment: It wasn't intended in that tone. I'll edit it. Can't edit it, I'll delete it.

Comment: The error message was indeed very clear, but I'm a beginner, and didn't know about the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the . use an _ instead

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

class Complex
{
   [...]
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an *identifier* here:

```
#ifndef Header1.h
        ^^^^^^^^^
```

and they [can not include `.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285827/1708801) in them, we can see this from the draft C++ standard section `16` *Preprocessing directives* paragraph *1* which includes the following grammar:

```
# ifdef identifier new-line groupopt
        ^^^^^^^^^^
# ifndef identifier new-line groupopt
         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

typically *include guards* are all caps and an underscores:

```
 #ifndef HEADER1_H
```

Answer (score 1):

Macro names can't contain periods. Rename it to `Header1` or `Header1h`.

As an aside, it's standard for most macros to be ALL_UPPERCASE.

Answer (score 1):

A macro name should not contain a dot. You'd better use

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H

...

#endif
```