# What is the default namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

what is the default namespace in c++？

```
#include<iostream>
class B{
 .....
}
int main(){
.....
}
```

so what namespace is class B in?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`B` is in the *global* `namespace`. It can be referred to unambiguously as `::B`.

Eric Z provides an excerpt from C++03 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269085