# C++ Access Specifiers: public to namespace only?

Tags: c++

In many other languages the default level of access for a class/struct and members is within the namespace scope, with `public` indicating that it is accessible outside of that namespace (or package, or library, or whatever they call their namespaces.)

In C++ I see I have the options `public` which makes it visible everywhere, `private` which is only for the class, and `protected` which is for this class and nested classes.

What about for only this namespace? That's often useful if you're writing a library that can access its own classes and their members, whilst restricting access by importing files.

Comment: Remember that C++ have `namespace`, but it seems your use of the term "namespace" means something else?

Comment: `namespace` can be extended (contrary to classes), so `friend namespace` really opens access.

Answer (score 0):

Your last remark is actually what the C++ `namespace` does.

Defining a class-attribute/-method whatever `public` makes it accessible outside of the class/class instance. But not outside of the `namespace` it's defined in.
To make something accessible outside of it's current `namespace` you have to use some sort of qualified name or a `using` directive. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace) for example.

Confusion may arise because per default e.g. without a explicit `namespace` definition scope around your class is defined in global [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995914/what-is-the-default-namespace) and thereby its public attributes/methods etc. are accesible anywhere in the global namespace.

Comment: But the importing file can still access class xyz with `namespace::xyz`, so it's not private. I mean to make it inaccessible to all but the current namespace, as `private` keyword does within a class scope.

Comment: @Alasdair Declare the intended-to-be-private class/struct/variable inside an unnamed namespace, i.e., one with no name, and it is only visible to the current translation unit, that is, the current `.cpp` file.

Comment: @Casey, that's a good idea, but can that be done with some members inside a class and not others?

Comment: Ok, if you want to do it like that I'm not sure namespaces are the right tool for that. Have you considered encapsulating the functionality within a pure virtual class?
Many people use them to define *interfaces* in C++.

Comment: @Alasdair You are confusing `class` and `namespace`, they are two different things in C++. `class`es define a type. `namespace`s prevent name collisions in code (and have the side effect of grouping code that logically would be related together, such as math-y types being in a `Math` namespace.)

Comment: @Casey I'm not confusing classes and namespaces. I'm saying that I want to have a member variable of a class that is accessible to code outside of the class but within the current namespace, but not accessible outside of that namespace. So if you import my library you cannot access that variable, but I can access it from another function outside of that class from within the same namespace.

Comment: @Alasdair Nevermind. I had a whole answer typed up before coming to the conclusion after trying it out that what you are asking does not work due to internal linkage properties, and how namespaces work; and, the fact that C++ is not other languages. Java is Java, C++ is C++, C# is C#.