# What is the meaning of :: when nothing is prefixed to it?

Tags: c++

I am working on a project involving sockets and QT. I want to use the socket functions from within sys/socket.h and not the ones that come with QT. (this is because I am following some tutorial type stuff).

The following code:

```
if (connect(sock, (const struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, (socklen_t) sizeof(servAddr)) < 0){    //connect to server
```

caused the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(int&,
>   const sockaddr*, socklen_t)'

I fixed this by adding :: in front of connect() like so:

```
if (::connect(sock, (const struct sockaddr *) &servAddr, (socklen_t) sizeof(servAddr)) < 0){    //connect to server
```

As I understand it I can use :: prefixed with a namespace but what does it mean in the current use? I only found out how to fix my error from a forum post but it did not explain the underlying thought behind it. Any other tricks for using :: .

Comment: The _global_ namespace ...

Comment: Explaining your problem, names are looked up by scope before overload resolution happens; so since you have an entity `MainWindow::connect`, if you write `connect` within MainWindow code then it only finds `MainWindow::connect`.  When you write `::connect` it means to use the global namespace's `connect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to take the expression after it from **global** scope. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269044/391161) for more details.