# What does :: mean in C++?

Tags: java, c++, jvm

There is one line of C++ code shown below.

```
return ::as_Register(value() >> 1);
```

I just want to know what's the meaning of the '::' which has nothing before it.

Is it the C++ syntax? Can there be nothing before '::'? Such as return ::myMalloc(size)?

The code is from jdk8 `openjdk/hotspot/src/cpu/x86/vm/vmreg_x86.inline.hpp`.

I am deeply studying the JDK.

Comment: `::as_Register` refers to the name `as_Register` in global scope.

Comment: Explanation of different scopes can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269012/global-scope-vs-global-namespace

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/484687/34509

Comment: How to do it in C: http://stackoverflow.com/a/623279/34509

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `::` references the global namespace:

```
void bar();

namespace some_namespace
{
    void bar();

    void foo()
    {
        // writing bar() would call some_namespace::bar()
        // but if we want to call the global bar() we have to write:
        ::bar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's C++. It means that you import this function from other namespaces.

Example:

```
namespace foo {
  void bar();
}

void bar();

namespace foo {
  void foobar()
  {
    bar(); // Means foo::bar()
    ::bar(); // Means bar() outside foo namespace
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!your answer is excellent,but I can only choose one correct answer,so I feel very sorry not to give you the correct answer.At last,very thanks to your help.@alkino