# C++ "::" without class name

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope, scope-resolution

I came across the following code structure in C++:

```
uint32_t AClass::Action(....)
{
..
      status = ::Action(...);
..
}
```

I am not sure what `::Action()` means. Which class does it belongs to? NOTE: the argument list of `::Action(...)` is different from `AClass::Action(...)`.

Answer (score 13):

The leading `::` just means that `Action` here refers to a non-member function in the global namespace, instead of referring to `AClass::Action` in the current namespace.

Comment: how do i find out where the root namespace is?

Comment: @dannycrane I suppose the root namespace could also be called the "default" namespace. Any code that isn't in an explicit `namespace` block is in the root namespace. All other namespaces are essentially "inside" the root namespace.

Comment: @RedRoboHood Would be nice if you can distinguish the root namespace from Global scope

Comment: @StraightLine They're more or less interchangeable. You can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269012/global-scope-vs-global-namespace) if you're especially interested.

Comment: There is such a thing as "the global namespace". There is no such thing as "the root namespace".

Answer (score -2):

::Action() mean it is a function under the the global namespace.

Comment: This is wrong. Anonymous namespaces are created by wrapping code in `namespace { /* ... */ }` blocks, not by usage of the leading `::` operator.

Comment: You're right I was mistaken