# C++ : namespace conflicting declaration error

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am unable to run the following code. As namesapces are different, why there are still showing errors as mentioned below?
     error: conflicting declaration 'NS2::Base B'
         NS2::Base B;

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace NS1
{
    class Base
    {
        int x=4;
        public:
            void disp()
            {
                cout<<x<<endl;
            }
    };
}

namespace NS2
{
    class Base
    {
        int x=7;
        public:
            void disp()
            {
                cout<<x<<endl;
            }
    };
}

int main()
{
    NS1::Base B;
    NS1:B.disp();
    NS2::Base B;
    NS2::B.disp();
}
```

Comment: You're creating to variables called `B`. This has nothing to do with the namespaces.

Comment: @Knoep, Ok, but the object B is created with different namespaces right?

Comment: no, `B` is a local variable in `main()`. it is not in a namespace. doing `NS1::B` is incorrect

Comment: See my answer, I hope this clarifies it. If not, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces contain only what is declared inside them, in your case the two classes `Base`. The two objects called `B` however are not declared in any namespace (but are both scoped to the function `main`), so you get a conflicting declaration error. It doesn't matter that the associated classes where declared in different namespaces.

Comment: the `B` declarations are not declared in the global namespace, or global scope (that'd be if they were defined above main), they are scoped to the function

Comment: @vu1p3n0x You're right, I should've been more careful. Give me a minute to figure out how to express this properly.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x What about that? I'm really not sure, what the correct terminology is.

Comment: thats fine. When talking about declarations, everything has a *scope* whether it be global, function, class, and a few others. for info: [Scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Scope wasn't the problem, but which namespace they're actually in (as this is what the question was all about). But accoding to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269012/global-scope-vs-global-namespace) it seems to be correct to say that they are not in any namespace at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just the `class Base` is part of `namespace NS1`,
B1 is just an object of type `NS1::Base` defined in `main()` not in `NS1`. Same goes for `B2` and `NS2`.
Thats why you can't call function using scope resolution operator on `B1`.
Objects are defined in `main()` so you have too keep names different too

```
int main()
{
    NS1::Base B1;
    B1.disp();
    NS2::Base B2;
    B2.disp();
}
```